# Why is my Exchange server making connections on port 25 to lots of strange (spam) domains?

Tags: exchange

In the logs of my Exchange server I see that it tries (a lot) to connect to the SMTP port of a bunch of spam domains.

How can this be? We use authentication for sending mail from our server, so it should not be a "spammers exploiting an open SMTP relay" kind of thing anyway?

I have also seen this before at other companies, and never understood why.

Example log excerpt (redacted with X letters in some parts):

```
2016-11-2XT17:XX:17.624Z,08D40XXXXXX40D98,SMTP,krhfe.tk,+,DnsConnectorDelivery 9dcexxxx-ec8x-4d3x-aefx-109adc8xxxxx;QueueLength=TQ=1;RN=1;.
2016-11-2XT17:XX:17.624Z,08D40XXXXXX40D98,SMTP,krhfe.tk,>,feh.krhfe.tk[45.79.XXX.XX]
2016-11-2XT17:XX:38.624Z,08D40XXXXXX40D98,SMTP,krhfe.tk,>,Failed connection to 45.79.XXX.XX:25 (TimedOut:0000274C)[TargetHost:feh.krhfe.tk:25|MarkedUnhealthy|FailureCount:15|NextRetryTime:2016-11-XXT17:XX:44.184Z][TargetIPAddress:45.79.XXX.XX:25|MarkedUnhealthy|FailureCount:15|NextRetryTime:2016-11-2XT17:XX:44.184Z]
2016-11-2XT17:XX:38.624Z,08D40XXXXXX40D98,SMTP,krhfe.tk,-,Messages: 0 Bytes: 0 (Retry : Unable to connect)
```

Does this **have** to mean that some account on the server has been hacked, or is there otherwise any possibility configuration-wise in Exchange to make this stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the queues. See if you have emails waiting to be delivered. Usually Out of the Office messages to a spam. Spam is always spoofed (unless said spammer is an idiot), so OOTO messages will hang around in the queues until they time out. I see this on larger environments more than anything.

The other main cause can be bounces to emails delivered to non-existent recipients. Using recipient filtering (usually third party as the native one has some flaws) will get round that issue.

RBLs are ok, if you are happy with some other party who is not accountable to anyone deciding what email you can and cannot receive (I am not a fan of them).

Comment: Thanks, marked as answer for multiple possible alternatives and good overview info. Could you please clarify what "RBLs" are though?

Comment: Reputation Black List

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is not a server issue, actually it is a normal behavior of DSNs (Delivery Status Notifications) under a server without spam filters configured.

Let me get it clear, when a spammer try to message mailboxes, usually it send older/obsolete/random mail accounts, which your server responds as invalid or unexisting (DSN) right?. Normally, the correct course of action in this situation is to fine tune your spam lists, first activating them with the `Install-AntiSpamAgents.ps1` script the  and then enabling RBL checks.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201691(v=exchg.160).aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351199(v=exchg.141).aspx